How to increase testing class coverage in Junit on boilerplate code
The view on code coverage is via IntelliJ using "Run
'Tests in Project' with Coverage"

Problem tree:

SonarCube is introduced and it requires 80% coverage
As there is much boilerplate, the coverage is ok, but between 70-75%

Although the quality gate of SonarQube could be reduced, the first approach is to raise the coverage on boilerplate code.
... this is not meaningful in the first place, but this questions objective is to raise the class coverage - purely technical.

Example one:
import java.util.List;

public class ResultData {
    public List<String> data;
}

public class ResultDataTest {

    @Test
     void testResultCollectionDataField() {
        // Create an instance of ResultCollection
        ResultData resultData = new ResultData();

        // Set values for the Data field
        resultData.data = Arrays.asList("Data1", "Data2", "Data3");

        // Assert that the Data field contains the expected values
        assertNotNull(resultData.data);
        assertEquals(3, resultData.data.size());
        assertEquals("Data1", resultData.data.get(0));
        assertEquals("Data2", resultData.data.get(1));
        assertEquals("Data3", resultData.data.get(2));
    }

    @Test
     void testEmptyResultCollectionDataField() {
        // Create an instance of ResultCollection without setting any data
        ResultData resultData = new ResultData();

        // Assert that the Data field is initially null
        assertNull(resultData.data);
    }
}

Coverage handed by Junit5/IntelliJ:

Class: 0% (0/1)
Method: 100% (0/0)
Line: 100% (0/0)

Example two:
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

public class InfoRequest {
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 8, max = 8)
    public String code;
}

import jakarta.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import jakarta.validation.Validation;
import jakarta.validation.Validator;
import jakarta.validation.ValidatorFactory;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.util.Set;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

public class InfoRequestTest {

    private Validator validator;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        // Set up a validator for validating the constraints
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidCode() {
        // Create an instance of InfoRequest and set a valid code
        InfoRequest infoRequest = new InfoRequest();
        infoRequest.code = "12345678"; // Valid, exactly 8 characters

        // Validate the object
        Set<ConstraintViolation<InfoRequest>> violations = validator.validate(infoRequest);

        // Assert that there are no violations
        assertTrue(violations.isEmpty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidCodeTooShort() {
        // Create an instance of InfoRequest and set an invalid (too short) code
        InfoRequest infoRequest = new InfoRequest();
        infoRequest.code = "1234"; // Invalid, less than 8 characters

        // Validate the object
        Set<ConstraintViolation<InfoRequest>> violations = validator.validate(infoRequest);

        // Assert that there's one violation due to size constraint
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }

}

Coverage handed by Junit5/IntelliJ:

Class: 0% (0/1)
Method: 100% (0/0)
Line: 100% (0/0)


To be answered ...

Why does the class coverage remain at zero?

.. Likewise ..

How to flip class coverage to 100% (1/1)?


Code coverage measures executed methods
your example classes do not contain any methods...

I understand the way, but do not want to alter production code. Code that is not necessary shall not be implemented, as it has to be maintained. Although technically correct, I can not accept your answer as 'the right way'.

that is ok :-D totally understandable

Maybe add functions in your classes, then create tests for those functions

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@wayne, I understand the way, but do not want to alter production code. Code that is not necessary shall not be implemented, as it has to be maintained. Although technically correct, I can not accept your answer as 'the right way'.
